# Processing: How does the "magic" functions work

Tags: java, event-handling, processing, control-p5

In processing if you want to register a mouse event listener, you just need to define a function with the name "mousepressed", "mousereleased", etc. and they "magically" become event listeners. This also happens to the controlP5 library I'm using, where all the functions named after a control widget "magically" become its event handler. I'm wondering how does Java handle this kind of magic? Where can I see some source code or topic regarding this pattern. I would like to know its mechanism since I can't define the listeners in main applet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has something to do with [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Comment: I think they use Reflection too... Processing is open source... https://github.com/processing/processing

Comment: Yeah that seems like the case!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Processing might use reflection for some stuff, but in the case of the mousePressed() functions, that's a simple matter of inheritance.

Processing contains a PApplet class, the source of which you can view here: https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java

At the time of this answer, line 3087 of the PApplet class is the mousePressed(MouseEvent) function that is called via an Event handler, which you can read about here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/

This mousePressed(MouseEvent) method calls the no-arg mousePressed() function, which is an empty function on line 3084.

When you write a Processing sketch, you're secretly **extending** PApplet. When you write a mousePressed() function in your sketch, you **override** the empty mousePressed() function of the PApplet class. Now when the PApplet class gets a MouseEvent from its MouseListener, it calls **your** mousePressed function. That's how inheritance works.

If you're asking a more specific question, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates exactly what you're talking about.